# Is there a way to get an unlimited inventory?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I find inventory management in this game to be rather tedious, I've a large number of upgrades as well as high-level items I can't use yet blocking my inventory slots. It is also rather tedious and time-consuming to check if any of the new items I found is an upgrade for any of my companions.

Is there a way to cheat or mod the game and increase the inventory limit significantly? I've already bought the inquisition perk upgrades for a larger inventory, but still run into issues regularly.

Comment: Doesn't this game have a multiplayer which would be affected by a cheat like this? IIRC it's kind of MMO Dungeon-ish (haven't played the game myself though).

Answer (score 2):

As it is: no. There are currently no known cheats, hacks or mods from a decent source. The few I came across are spam and malicious attempts to obtain information.

It's very likely that this will never happen for console versions either, though perhaps there are possibilities unknown to me for modded consoles.

As for the PC version, I guess there's always a possibility that mods may be created. Don't count on it though, as the game's based on Battlefield's Frostbite engine, which is apparently notoriously hard to mod. Other games using it don't have a wide range of tools available, either.